# ClickOnce background update + copy old user settings + delete old version

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, .net-4.5

The following question may have been asked, if so please guide me accordingly.

I have a requirement where I need to achieve the following.

```
1. Check for new version of the application.
2. Download the latest version in a background mode without troubling the user current operation.
3. Prompt the user about the new version to "save the current work" and then exit and restart the application
4. After the application update is complete, remove the older version, but copy the old user settings file to the new version installed folder
```

For #1, #2 and #3, I have successfully achieved what I need using reference: http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Taming_ClickOnce_ndash_taking_charge_of_updates.aspx.

But for #4 I am not sure how to proceed on this.

Answer (score 0):

With ClickOnce your user settings file won't be deleted so you don't need to manage version folders or change files. ClickOnce already does that for you.

However for some cases you may have to perform several actions, like updating the local database schema. If so, you can create a config file containing the last application version number on startup. After the application starts, you check that the current version is the same as the one in the file, if yes no update has happened, if no the application has been updated so you can perform your new version init method and update the application version in the file.